# Deleting item in file in c#

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I want to delete item in file via c#, I tried to overwrite it but nothing happens when StreamWriter is false, and all items are deleted when StreamWriter is true. I create WinForm app. This is my code below for button which deletes selected item in listBox:

```
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        count--;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("e:\\list.txt", true))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                arr[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = "";
                sw.Write(arr[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would help if we had some example data with content of your variables and of your files, and what do you expect.

Comment: Text files generally have to be rewritten in their entirety when you want to modify something in them.

Comment: `arr[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = "";` why is this inside the loop on i? You just need to execute it once before the loop, that would give the same result.

Comment: what is `arr` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using arr you could use a List<> and then Remove the selected item.

Other thing, I think you don't need to use a count variable because there is a ListBox.Item.Size method.

Comment: It doesn't work with List. Now program falls, and error is: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index...

Comment: void func()
        {
            List<string> lista = File.ReadAllLines("e:\\lista.txt").ToList();
            lista.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            File.WriteAllLines("e:\\lista.txt", lista.ToArray());
        }